# Legend in Seaborn Scatter plot: How to limit the number of decimal places?

Tags: format, seaborn, legend, scatter-plot

Is there a way to limit the number of decimal places in the legend of a seaborn scatter plot?

here is the code I have written so far. Cannot find a way to format the number in the legend (set by the variable z)

```
fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()

sns.scatterplot(x='x', 
                y='y', 
                data=df,
                size='z', 
                sizes=(50, 300),
                size_norm=(0,0.5),
                palette=custom_palette,
                ax=ax0
               )

ax0.set(xscale='log')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: According to [this github issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1703) the problem should be corrected since end of 2019. Did you try the latest seaborn version?

Comment: Hi @JohanC. thanks for your comment. I checked the seaborn version was 0.90. I just updated it and now the problem dissapeared.